# SVN tree conflicts on merge after reintegrate branch

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, versioning

I have a problem. Normally I work using Tortoise SVN and every month to work on the development of the code I use a branch structure that looks like this:

```
trunk ----- b1
|           |
| --------->|
|           |----- b2
|           |       |
| --------->|       |
| <----[1]--|       |
|           X       |
| -----[2]--------> |
|                   |
|                   |
```

After the step [1] (reintegration branch to trunk), I remove unnecessary branch b1. Then I try to merge the changes from the current trunk to b2. Unfortunately, when you try to merge the trunk version [2], which was established after the integration of trees get a lot of conflicts. What is the reason and what should be the correct order when you try to create a new branch from the branch, not the trunk?

Comment: It's so necessary delete the first branch? Why? I see no good reason to generate a second branch from a deleted branch.

Comment: In accordance with the user's SVN, do not work on a branch after reintegration into her trunk.
Sometimes before reintegration begins to create additional functionality that bid farewell merged to trunk, some time after [1]. They should develop the functionality currently contained in b1. So I create a branch from a branch b1

Comment: This approach is incorrect. After integrated, the branch should never be integrated again. The correct is create another branch from a trunk revision. That's an issue in your process.